# Nightmarejs - How could I read table rows content?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, bots, nightmare

I'm writing a little nightmare script that types names in a web form and reads results printed in a table. I've made the input typing already and get the table results like this:

```
{ jQuery110205953448106032428: 124 }
```

So I don't know how to read rows from this element.

My current script is:

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare')
const nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true })

nightmare
  .goto('https://rnped.segob.gob.mx/')
  .click('small#leyendacomun')
  .wait(2000)
  .type('input#comun_c_nombre', 'María')
  .type('input#comun_c_apaterno', 'Hernández')
  .click('button#busca_comun')
  .wait(2000)
  .evaluate(function () {
      return document.querySelector('table#t_comun')
      // Here I select and return the <table>
  })
  .end()
  .then(function (result) {
      console.log(result)
      //  Here I get { jQuery110205953448106032428: 124 }
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
  });
```

How could I get the table rows from that query selector?

Answer (score 0):

The result of evaluate can not be a reference to a DOM element like in your code. Do all the data extraction inside your `evaluate()` function, e.g., like this:

```
  // ...
  .wait(2000)
  .evaluate(function () {
      // get table and prepare result
      const table = document.querySelector('table#t_comun'),
            result = [];

      // get rows
      const rows = table.querySelectorAll( 'tr' );
      for( let i=0; i<rows.length; i++ ) {

        // get cells
        let cells = rows[i].querySelectorAll( 'td' );

        // get contents
        let row = [];
        for( j=0; j<cells.length; j++ ) {
          row.push( cells[i].innerHTML );
        }

        // add to result
        result.push( row );
      }

      // done, return result
      return result;
  })
  .end()
  // ...
```

Comment: Ok, many thanks! And how could I iterate through all the pages of the results table, I have to do it in the evaluate function too?

Comment: You can test in your own browser: Write a script that extracts all data you need into an array or object. Then use the same code in the `evaluate()` function and return the results.

Comment: @RameshKumar What kind of error on which call of `querySelectorAll()`? Have your verified that the previous elements (at least `table`) are not null?